# Docker を用いて macOS(10.13 High Sierra) 上に Linux 環境を構築したい

Tags: linux, docker, docker-for-mac

ほぼタイトル通りの内容の質問です。
ネットで調べてもどうすればDockerを用いてLinux仮想環境を自分のPC上に構築できるのかがわかりません。
既にDockerの自分のPCへのインストールは完了しているのですが、そこから先でどのような手順を取ればLinux仮想環境を構築して開発ができるのかわかりません。
より具体的には、Cコンパイラをとある資料をもとに作成しようと思っているのですが、その資料における想定開発環境がLinuxとなっていて「macOSとLinuxではアセンブリのソースレベルで微妙に差異があるので、DockerなどでLinux環境を用意して開発を行うようにして下さい」と資料にはあるので、DockerでLinux環境を用意しそこでコンパイラの開発やテストを行いたいのです...。
ですので、どなたか解決方法がわかる方がいればご教授頂けると助かります。

Comment: Linux環境を構築、とはどのような状況を想定していますか？例えば、ターミナルから `docker run hello-world` など実行すると（正常に動作すれば）Linux環境が立ち上がって終了する様子を観察できます。

Comment: @firebird さん、その事情を質問文に含めてくださると答えやすくなりそうです。一般に、もし解決したい問題の背景に別の問題があるなら全部書いてしまうことをお勧めします :)

Answer (score 2):

次のコマンドを実行すれば、
Docker を使って Ubuntu (Linux環境) を対話的に操作することが可能です。

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

次のステップとして、
ここに開発環境等を構築していくということになるかと思いますが、
コンテナは、このままでは変更された設定や、
作成されたファイルを維持することができません。

単純なアプリケーションを、
Docker を使ってビルド、実行している例がありましたので、
こちらの記事を参考にしてください。

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Comment: ファイルを維持することができないってどういうことですか..?

Comment: ファイルを維持するには具体的にどのような解決を試みるべきでしょうか...?

Comment: 上記の `docker run ...` はコンテナを実行しているのですが、コンテナというのは状態の変更を維持するという目的に向いていません。なぜそうなのかは、ここでは説明しきれないため、Docker のドキュメントを読んでいただくしかありません。

Comment: 取りうる手段としては、https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55204/8336 で紹介している Docker を使ってアプリケーションをビルドする方法を学ぶか、https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55205/8336 の仮想マシンを用いるかになります。
個人的には、簡単なので後者の方法をお勧めします。

Answer (score 2):

Cコンパイラの開発を Linux で行いたいというのが目的であれば、
[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) をインストールして、
そこで Ubuntu などの Linux Distro を使うほうが、
手間が少なくて、簡単かなと思いますよ。